# IntegerField doesnt accept negative number django

Tags: mysql, django, integer

i try to make some calculate using `annotate` and `Sum,F` in django 2.2 and then the output `output_field=IntegerField` but sometimes the result of calculating will be negative `number < 0` and it wont accept the negative number and raise this error :
i use mysql version : 8 as the database

> 1690, "BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in(some fields name)

all fields are `IntegerField` in `models.py` except `a` field

```
a = models.PositiveIntegerField()
b = models.IntegerField()
c = models.IntegerField()
```

this is my query

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
            income=Sum(
                (F('somefield_name__a') * F('somefield_name__b')) - F('somefield_name__c'),output_field=IntegerField())
                )
```

is there something accept positive and negative integer at the same time ? please

thanks ..

Comment: Please post the corresponding model for this, also please be more specific than "some fields name"

Comment: all fields are IntegerField except a field in the query i wrote , and updated the post

Comment: Without knowing the size of the number you are getting as a result or the full model, it's too hard to say what is wrong here.

Comment: i updated now , please can you check it again

Comment: i didnt use any limited number to fields n and the sizes are small enough something like this (a=3 , b=2 and c=10) the result will be -4

Comment: @MichaelHawkins  i changed PositiveIntegerField to IntegerField now it fixed , thanks alot

Comment: Ok, no problem. That is why we needed to see the model in its entirety